# Filtering inner arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

How do I filter if an array is inside another array?

How should I loop this?

```
var jobs = [
    {
        'id': '1',
        'departments': [{'name': 'Finance'}],
        'offices': [{'name': 'US'}, {'name': 'Brazil'}]
    },
    {
        'id': '1',
        'departments': [{'name': 'Finance'}],
        'offices': [{'name': 'Paris'}, {'name': 'China'}]
    }
];

var results = jobs.filter(function(o)) {
    return o.offices[0].name == 'US';
} // get office US;
```

[jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/f48uo03y/)

Comment: `jobs.filter(j => j.offices.some(o => o.name === "US"))` Use `some` to see if one of the objects inside the `offices` array matches your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to filter an array by a value that might exist in an internal array, you can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on the internal array. The method `Array#some` returns true, and stop iteration, if at least one element of the array meets the criteria.

```js
var jobs = [{"id":"1","departments":[{"name":"Finance"}],"offices":[{"name":"US"},{"name":"Brazil"}]},{"id":"1","departments":[{"name":"Finance"}],"offices":[{"name":"Paris"},{"name":"China"}]}];

var jobsWithoutUs = jobs.filter(function(job) {
  return job.offices.some(function(office) {
    return office.name === 'US';
  });
});

console.log(jobsWithoutUs);
```